# Error React Native: Unable to resolve "./calendar" from "node_modules\react-native-calendars\src\index.ts"

Tags: javascript, react-native, calendar, react-native-calendars

I am writing a program on React Native "ToDo" and I need to make a calendar to schedule tasks. I use the extension react-native-calendars.
But I get an error:

> Unable to resolve "./calendar" from "node_modules\react-native-calendars\src\index.ts"

In the code, I do:

```
import { Calendar } from "react-native-calendars";
<Calendar/>`
```

I already uninstalled the extension and downloaded it again

Comment: Have you rebuild your app using npx react-native run-android and/or npx react-native run-ios?

Answer (score 1):

### Possible solutions:

1. Reinstall node_modules.(Uninstall them then again install).
   OR
2. Rebuild your Project.